# docker wordpress container can't connect to database container

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, mariadb

I've been using docker to build wordpress apps for some days. I got some working but now I don't know why I can get to connect the database container and the wordpress container.

I've reduced the failing condiguration to the simplest possible.

Right now I have the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
wordpress:
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8080:80

db:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

which is an exact copy of this official example:

https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/

(scroll down to "... via docker-compose").

If I do composer up with this file I got the following relevant log entries:

```
Creating miqueladell_db_1
Creating miqueladell_wordpress_1
Attaching to miqueladell_db_1, miqueladell_wordpress_1
db_1        | Initializing database
```

…lots of initialization…

```
wordpress_1 | Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in - on line 10
```

…this goes on for a while, db_1 says it's initializing and wordpress_1 says it can connect
and then…

```
db_1        | MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
```

…some more database messages…

```
db_1        | 2016-01-12 14:34:46 139698309449664 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
wordpress_1 | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.5. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
wordpress_1 | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.5. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
wordpress_1 | [Tue Jan 12 14:34:47.180996 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) PHP/5.6.17 configured -- resuming normal operations
wordpress_1 | [Tue Jan 12 14:34:47.181253 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

…at that momment if I browse to the wordpress endpoint I got…

```
wordpress_1 | 192.168.99.1 - - [12/Jan/2016:14:34:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 586 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
```

And an **Error establishing a database connection** on the front end.

I've pasted the full log here in case someone want's to take a look: http://pastebin.com/Z9U2iMsH

I've got my environment running before and I am sure that if not this particular example I have been able to run the containers and connect to the database with some of the examples I tried (without luck) today so I guess there is something wrong with my environment but I don't know how to debug it.

I've removed all containers, all images, re-donwloaded the images and rebuilt de containers. Even tested everyithing on a enpty folder with a newly created docker-compose.yml file.

In fact as reading the logs it seemed that maybe the wordpress process was exhausting its tries I have even restarted the wordpress container *while* the database container was already up and the result is the same.

Just in case it's relevant I'm running all of this locally on a mac using the docker quickstart terminal as descrived here:

https://docs.docker.com/mac/step_one/

and **docker -v** says:

```
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5
```

**EDIT:** Just tried using:

```
image: wordpress:4.4
```

instead of "no tag" which downloads latest (4.4.1 at the time of writing) and it works. So it seems that is a bug introduced on 4.4.1

I've oppened one here

https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/120

I'll keep the question open just in case but it seems quite  clear that is a bug

Comment: could you manage to get the content of the PHP error log?

Comment: It was a bug and it's solved. I'll keep the PHP error log in mind next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a bug on the version 4.4.1 of the wordpress container.

I've oppened an issue here https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/120 and it's solved now.

Thanks all!

Comment: why did the `docker-compose pull` solve your issue in the end?

Comment: because the dev did  update the image with a fix XD
Docker pull was just to pull the latest image

Comment: Or maybe not... I did assume that and I've went to check the pushes on github and everything is 5 days old ... strange